# background-repeat: repeat; vs. background-repeat: space; vs. background-repeat: round;?

Tags: css, background

I'm reading [CSS3 Background & Border Module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/), and for the `background-repeat` property, I see two new values, namely `space` and `round`.

While it has the description of what they do, I can't figure out how they differ from the ordinary `repeat` value. The example given there is not really a good one, and I can get the result with `repeat` value either.

Can anyone please make a good differentiation between them, preferably giving some graphical cues?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting [Mozilla developer network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background-repeat), emphasis mine:

> `repeat`: The image is repeated in the given direction as much as needed
>   to cover the whole background image painting area. **The last image
>   may be clipped** if the whole thing won't fit in the remaining area.
>
> `space`: The image is repeated in the given direction as much as
>   needed to cover most of the background image painting area, **without
>   clipping an image**. The remaining non-covered space is **spaced out
>   evenly** between the images. The first and last images touches the
>   edge of the element. [...]
>
> `round`: The image is repeated in the given direction as much as needed
>   to cover most of the background image painting area, **without
>   clipping** an image. If it doesn't cover exactly the area, **the tiles
>   are resized** in that direction in order to match it.

[image]

Comment: EDIT: Added self explanatory image to Chowlett answer